# How can we detect an object of a given shape and colour in python using open cv? I can't do both things simultaneously

Tags: python, opencv

I tried writing the code but was not able to do both detections simultaneously

Answer (score -2):

Using HAAR cascades to train for the shape. But will be limited due to orientations etc. Tensorflow can be used. However, detection by color and shape will be a bigger problem.